# Is it possible to run slurm commands within a singularity container?

Tags: docker, machine-learning, containers, slurm, singularity-container

I want to go into a container with singularity and then run slurm commands. For example:

```
singularity shell docker://tensorflow/tensorflow:1.0.0-gpu-py3
```

then within it run the script that I do want to run my script:

```
python tf_test.py
```

the contents of tf_test is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.random_uniform((3,2)))
```

the issue I have is that the container doesn't know I am in a HPC or that slurm exists. Is it possible to **only run slurm commands after we are in the container**? I am particularly interested in using `sbatch`. Using srun and then going in the container is cheating and not what I want.

Comment: I found [this description](https://info.gwdg.de/wiki/doku.php?id=wiki:hpc:usage_of_slurm_within_a_singularity_container) of directories that need to be bound and configuration inside the container.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on version you're running, but this should work for the 2.4.x series.

You can install slurm in the container, or if it's mounted on your cluster at say:

```
/apps/sched/slurm/[ver]
```

You can use the -B / --bind option to bind mount it like:

```
singularity shell -B /apps/sched/slurm/[ver] -B /etc/slurm
```

But, the job will **not** be in the container when ran. To force that you can can submit a run script that executes something like:

```
singularity exec docker://tensorflow/tensorflow:1.0.0-gpu-py3 python /path/to/tf_test.py
```

**Edit:**
Once you get this where you're happy with the run, IMO it'd be good to build a Singularity image from the Docker source. In the definition file, setup a %runscript section like

```
%runscript
    python "$@"
```

You can then just submit:

```
/path/to/imagename.img /path/to/tf_test.py
```

Singularity images can be ran like an application, and by default it will execute whatever is in the %runscript section.